# From Javascript Int to a Java String

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, string, int

So I have a variable in Javascript that can be both String and int, I need to send it to a java method. I though that, since it's easier to change a number into a string instead of the opposite, I set the variable into a string. I'm gonna post some code

This is obviously the javascript, the variable valore is the one that can be both Int and string

```
$(".save").click(function() {

                var valore = $("#valore").val();                
                var connettore = $("#connettore option:selected").text().split(" ").join("");       

                $.get("select"+connettore+".do", {

                    nomecampo: $("#colonnaRiferim").val().toLowerCase(),
                    valore: valore

                }, function (data) {
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.connettore.length; i++) {
                                var conn = data.connettore[i];                      
                            }
                        }
                );
```

This is the Java function

```
@RequestMapping("selectCompensi")
@ResponseBody
@Transactional
public ModelWrapper<List<TracciatoCompensi>> selectCompensi(@RequestParam String nomecampo, 
    @RequestParam String valore){       
    Session s = hibernateFactory.getCurrentSession();
    ModelWrapper<List<TracciatoCompensi>> resp = new ModelWrapper<List<TracciatoCompensi>>();
    Criteria c = s.createCriteria(TracciatoCompensi.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq(nomecampo, valore));
    List<TracciatoCompensi> aList = (List<TracciatoCompensi>) c.list();

    Query query = s.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO tracciato_compensi_clone (CODICEORDINE, CODICESERVIZIO, CODICEUNIVOCOCOMPONENTE, COEFFICIENTECANONEMESE, "+nomecampo+", compensi1, rev, mod_time, mod_user) ("
                +"SELECT CODICEORDINE, CODICESERVIZIO, CODICEUNIVOCOCOMPONENTE, COEFFICIENTECANONEMESE, "+nomecampo+", "+nomecampo+", rev, mod_time, mod_user FROM tracciato_compensi WHERE "+nomecampo+" = '"+valore+"')");                

    resp.put("connettore", aList);
    query.executeUpdate();
    return resp;
}
```

You can ignore the Query, that stuff works, as so does the criteria and the rest. My problem seems obvious, if valore is numeric, then the function crash,
I tried to add a random character to the number, and I tried to convert it using toString() into javascript but even if I use the isNumeric() function of jquery and it says that it isn't numeric, it still crashes

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: if valore is "5" or 5 doesn't mater the query string will be ...&valore=5

Comment: it's not difficult to change int to String, parseInt(val) in JS and Integer.parseInt(val) in Java...

Comment: 1) I get this error "java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer"
2) as I said, the problem is not into the query
3)If I recall correctly parseInt changes a String into an int and not an int into a String

Answer (score 0):

The method you're looking for probably is [String.valueOf(Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)):

```
    String valore1 = "5";
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(valore1));

    int valore2 = 5;
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(valore2));
```

gives:

```
5
5
```

in the console.

Comment: I know how to convert an int into a string and viceversa both in javascript and in java, the problem is that the java method seems to see an integer, when I send $("#valore").val(); to it in javascript, if there's a single number it'll go mad.